# Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous grails?

Tags: grails, hql

I have a RaceRegistration domain that extends Registration

```
class RaceRegistration extends Registration{
```

The Registration class has mapping tableperhierarchy set to false so we have two different tables registration and race_registration in the db.

```
abstract class Registration extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{

static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
```

This line is throwing

```
RaceRegistration.executeUpdate('update RaceRegistration r set r.raceParticipant.bibNumber = null where r.id in (:ids)', [ ids: ids])
```

the following exception

```
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver: MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException occurred when processing request: [GET] /roadrace/bibs/reassignBibNumbers/976945 - parameters:
sort: asc
Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. Stacktrace follows:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4098)
```

looks like since there are two different tables when i do where r.id it is confused which table it should look registration or race_registration.

Is there a way to disambiguate this in the hql query?

i appreciate any insights.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing it's the BaseEntity that's causing the issue, what does that look like? Can you temporarily take that out of the hierarchy and run the example above?

Comment: hi mike thanks for the comment, even after commenting out extends BaseEntity it is still giving the same error.

Comment: I have a project that I added simple controller/service to test something similar to your setup with mysql which seems to work as expected - https://github.com/leadtrip/g519gormInheritance/blob/master/grails-app/services/wood/mike/CarService.groovy note the inclusion of logSql: true on the dataSource config in application.yml which you may find useful

Comment: thanks mike for the help. something is blocking it to work. for now i found an alternate way to solve the issue. i ended up flushing the session manually and using .save() because the code depends on the bibassignment null being executed. so i did CompositeEvent.withSession { session ->

   session.flush()
  }

Comment: btw i am using a really old grails 2.2.